# android animation when gridview's item is clicked

Tags: android, animation, gridview, adapter, translate-animation

I'm implemented list of music albums with adapter and gridView. When it`s item i mean play button is clicked i animated 'animation Img' to bottom of screen. The problem is that 'animation img' is moving back side of gridview items not top of views.I wanna implement this animation like kugou music player [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kugou.android).

[image]

Here is my code:
Gridview list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animImg"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/anim"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="7dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="7dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</GridView>
```

Gridview items view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:weightSum="11">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/album"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumPlayBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:src="@drawable/play_button"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/albumName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Album name"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/artistName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Artist name"/>
```

and my doAnimation method:

```
public void doAnimation(int[] originalPos) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(animImg.getWidth(), animImg.getHeight());
    animImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(originalPos[0], originalPos[0],
            originalPos[1], height);
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    animImg.startAnimation(anim);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anybody have an idea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue on my own in terms of adding `animImg.bringToFront();` after `animImg.startAnimation(anim);` method.